# How can I call flex project from other flex project?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

I have **2 flex projects** which were create in *flash builder 4.5*.....**how** can i **call one** project **from second**??? the best would execute to the same window.... I'm interesting about both possibility (in browser and air too).

thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean "execute to the same window"? Start playing another flash movie in the same player or loading external movie and execute inside current one with ability to remove?

Comment: loading external movie and execute inside current one with ability to remove..

Comment: I find SWFLoader..so i make var a:SWFLoader = new SWFLoader(); a.source="otherSWF.swf"; this.addElement(a);    In this moment is load external project but not with correct size ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to share code between two projects is to create a 3rd project that is an ActionScript/Flex Library. This would encapsulate the common code between multiple projects (Flex/AIR/Pure AS3) and compile them into one .swc file.

In any of the projects you need to access that code, you can right click on the project -> Properties -> Flex Build Path -> Library Path Tab (at the top) -> Add Project -> Select that common actionscript library.

The hack way to share code right click on the project -> Properties -> Flex Build Path -> Source Path Tab (at the top) -> Add Folder. Select the file system path to where you want to pull external resources into your project. Generally this is not recommended because it makes the importing project less portable when you want to share the project with other developers. They'll find out the hard way that the file system path you selected may not exist on their own local machines.